# Beamer Title Page Text Rearrangement

Tags: beamer, xetex, formatting, titles, slideshow

I have made the following title page in Xelatex Beamer using an online template. I am happy with the outlook. I just want the order of the logo and Author swaped with Lecture topic and date. I want Lectue topic and date in the middle and Logo and Author information in last row with some extra space between them. All other settings like in the footnote are appropriate. I am attaching the code as well as image for the consideration.

In image I have marked with red and blue color swapping direction. The green portion need not to be changed so they remain same for all slides. Thank you in advance.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{beamer}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\usetheme{Madrid}

\usecolortheme{seahorse}

\usefonttheme{professionalfonts}
\usefonttheme{serif} 
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont[Ligatures=TeX]{Futura Medium.ttf}
\newfontfamily\fb{Futura Bold.ttf}

\useinnertheme{circles}

\title[Name of the Course]{Name of the Course}

\author[Lecture 1: Topic of the Lecture]{}

\titlegraphic{%
  \begin{picture}(0,0)
    \put(-70,110){\makebox(0,0)[rt]{\includegraphics[width=1cm]{logo}}}
  \end{picture}}
\institute[]{{\fb{Author Name}} \\ \smallskip
\text{Electrical and Computer Engineering} \\ \smallskip
\textit{xxx@yyy.zz}}

\date[Author Name]{
Lecture 1: Topic of the Lecture \\ May 04, 2022}

\begin{document}
\boldmath

\begin{frame}
    \titlepage 
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image: Red and Blue need to be Swaped and Green is Fine]

Comment: Hi and welcome to TeX.SX! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can redefine the title page to arrange the information in whatever order you want:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{beamer}

%\usepackage{graphicx}
%\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\usetheme{Madrid}

\usecolortheme{seahorse}

\usefonttheme{professionalfonts}
\usefonttheme{serif} 


\useinnertheme{circles}

\title[Name of the Course]{Name of the Course}

\author[Lecture 1: Topic of the Lecture]{}

\titlegraphic{%
  \begin{picture}(0,0)
    \put(-70,50){\makebox(0,0)[rt]{\includegraphics[width=1cm]{example-image-duck}}}
  \end{picture}}
\institute[]{{{Author Name}} \\ \smallskip
\text{Electrical and Computer Engineering} \\ \smallskip
\textit{xxx@yyy.zz}}

\date[Author Name]{
Lecture 1: Topic of the Lecture \\ May 04, 2022}

\makeatletter
\setbeamertemplate{title page}
{
  \vbox{}
  \vfill
  \begingroup
    \centering
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[sep=8pt,center,rounded=true,shadow=true]{title}
      \usebeamerfont{title}\inserttitle\par%
      \ifx\insertsubtitle\@empty%
      \else%
        \vskip0.25em%
        {\usebeamerfont{subtitle}\usebeamercolor[fg]{subtitle}\insertsubtitle\par}%
      \fi%     
    \end{beamercolorbox}%
    \vskip1em\par
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[sep=8pt,center,rounded=true,shadow=true]{date}
      \usebeamerfont{date}\insertdate
    \end{beamercolorbox}
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[sep=8pt,center,rounded=true,shadow=true]{author}
      \usebeamerfont{author}\insertauthor
    \end{beamercolorbox}
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[sep=8pt,center,rounded=true,shadow=true]{institute}
      \usebeamerfont{institute}\insertinstitute
    \end{beamercolorbox}\vskip0.5em
    {\usebeamercolor[fg]{titlegraphic}\inserttitlegraphic\par}
  \endgroup
  \vfill
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
    \titlepage 
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you samcarter_is_at_topansw